# Docker connect to postgres with specific host address

Tags: postgresql, docker

I want to connect to container with postgres DB by some unique name instead 127.0.0.1 address.

There is specific flag `--add-host=name:ipaddrs` that will add routing to /etc/hosts file internally in container, but it isn't that I want.

```
docker run --rm --add-host=postgresdb:127.0.0.1 -p 5430:5432 -d --name=docker-postgres-image -e DB_HOST=postgresdb -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pspostgres -e POSTGRES_DB=app postgres
```

How I can change default routing to connect to container from localhost(127.0.0.1):5430 to any character words for ex. postgres-db-service:5430 ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope understand you. I think you need a [hostname](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/) in your container, you can do this using the flag --hostname.
So your command will look like this:

```
docker run -d --rm --hostname postgres-db-service \
    -p 5430:5432 \
    --name=docker-postgres-image \
    -e DB_HOST=postgres-db-service \
    -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres \
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pspostgres \
    -e POSTGRES_DB=app \
    postgres
```

Comment: Don't work in my case, try to  use command:docker run --rm -d --hostname=postgresdb --ip=127.0.0.1 --name=docker-postgres-image -p 5430:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pspostgres -e POSTGRES_DB=app -v /usr/nicko/docker/mount/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres

Comment: But there is another option to add routing explicitly to /etc/hosts file: 127.0.0.1 postgresdb. And connection establish with URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgresdb:5430/postgres.

Is it right way?

Comment: Could you try without flag --ip=127.0.0.1?